# HTML element doesn't resize correctly - spacing?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to keep the same ratio for my html elements and same distance but whenever I resize the window, the objects don't have the same spacing. I am not sure what exactly is issue as I have played around with the margins/padding and neither of those work.

[Screen smaller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2RSA.png)

[Should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bwu6N.png)

Comment: Sorry, can you show the us html and css code?

Answer (score 2):

Its better if you can use bootstrap classes instead of using custom css. Anyway you can use this.

```
.parent{
 display: flex;
 justify-content:space-between;
}

.child{
 display: inline-block
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below basic styling to fix above issue:

```
.parent {
 display: flex;
 justify-content:space-between;
}

.child {
 width: 100%;
 padding: 1rem;
}
```